# In rails product_id is not taking to the method shows error as ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GetproductsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As i am new to rails, i cant pinpoint the error..
I am writing a method to get data by giving the only prod_id from the URL. I give the URL as localhost:3000/getproducts/PR1.josn to get the data in json format. But it shows an error that

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GetproductsController#show

Couldn't find Product without an ID

Rails.root: /root/Railsapps/Shopping
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/getproducts_controller.rb:12:in `show'
```

**Here i am giving my getproducts.rb which is controller**

```
class GetproductsController < ApplicationController

   def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:prod_id]) 
    respond_to do|format|
      format.html  {render show.html.erb}
       format.xml  #{ render :xml => @product }
      format.json {render json:@product}
    end
      end

end
```

**My model is product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :prod_id
end
```

**my show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Model Name:</b>
  <%= @product.model_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Brand Name:</b>
  <%= @product.brand_name %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is most likely that Rails is taking the parameter you provide and assuming that it's called `id`, so that when you ask for `prod_id`, there is no such parameter. This is the default for a show action - the parameter is assumed to be named `id`. You then try to find by params[:prod_id], which is nil, since params (probably) is just `{:id => 'PR1'}`.

You can fix this either by passing `params[:id]` instead of `params[:prod_id]` in your `Product.find_by` call, or by modifying your routes.rb file, thus:

```
resources :getproducts, :except => [:show]

get 'getproducts/:prod_id' => 'getproducts#show'
```

First, you tell Rails not to use the default show route for this controller (that's the `:except` option). Then, you define your own route, specifying the name of the parameter. This way, when you call `getproducts/PR1`, 'PR1' will get passed as `params[:prod_id]`. You need to exclude the default first because Rails will use the first route that matches, so as long as the default still exists, it's defined by the `resources` call.

Comment: Sir thank u so mch for giving me the answer.. but can u explain me how to set the routes explicitly?? my routes.rb is resources :getproducts

Comment: Thank u sir.. sir i have an another doubt.. To find an item we use only the id as pk, like find(params[:id]).... But in my project i have to find the items by givind the product catgeory, In general this sql may be like "select model_name from products where prod_cat=?"
but this prod_cat is not any key (like primary key) in that table.. So in ruby is it possible to make a query for this or not???

Comment: @PavanKumar In general, finding records in ruby using Relations mirrors the SQL. The query you describe would be something like this: `Product.where(:prod_cat => 'category name')`. It doesn't matter to rails if this is a key or not, though if you're doing this frequently with a large number of product records, you might wish to index the products table on the prod_cat column for improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you also write the route that you have for that url in config/routes.rb?

On your model, you need to tell rails that your primary key is not "id" as expected, so do

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_primary_key :prod_id

   attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :prod_id
end
```

Then you can do

```
Product.find(params[:id])
```

and it should work :)

Comment: Thank u sir.. Thank u so much.. but when i give the url as localhost:3000/getproducts/PR1.json, it gives the data in json format.. But when i give as localhost:3000/getproducts/PR1 then it gives error as SystemStackError in GetproductsController#show

stack level too deep

Comment: In your controller, your action responds to: .xml, .json and .html (without the .html actually). When you do PR1.json, it uses the block inside format.json, when you do getproducts/PR1, it will use the block within the .html and will render the html view, so its probably a problem in the view show.html.erb, or either in the layout.html.erb, check that you have a **yield** in the layout and try by deleting the content of the show.html.erb to see if it works (if it does, then the problem is within the code of the view)

Comment: sir i have some doubts regarding to this.. can u invite me to chat?? plz.. I need u r help

Comment: Came into this room and I'll help in any way I can: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails